# probability of exactly, atleast, and expected number

Tags: probability, statistics

The people discovered that 54% of refugees who ask for asylum in the New York immigration court win asylum, but only 12% are granted asylum in the Florida immigration court.

Assume that you randomly select 20 refugees who are asking for asylum in the Florida immigration court.

A. find the probability that exactly five asylum seekers are granted asylum.

$${20}\choose{5}$$ $$= 15504$$
$$(15504)(.12)^5$$ $$= 0.385789133$$
$$(0.385789133)(.88)^{(20-5)}$$ $$= 0.056700916$$

B. find the probability that at least three asylum seekers are granted asylum. 
(I used the same formula above to find the probability for each x value)

x | P(x)

---

0 | 0.077562794

1 | 0.211534892

2 | 0.274033847

3 | 0.224209503

$$ P(x=0) + P(x=1) + P(x=2) + P(x=3) $$ $$= 0.787341026$$
$$1 - 0.787341026 = 0.212658974$$

C. what is the expected number on asylum seekers who win their cases?

$$(n)(p)(q)$$ $$(20)(.12)(.88) = 2.112$$

are A,B,C correct?

for b, since probabilities must add up to 1, it is ok to find the probability for 0 - 3 and subtract that number from 1 to get the probability of atleast 3? (3,4,5,6,7,...) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the random variable $X$ is the number accepted, then the probability that $X$ is at least $3$ is $\Pr(X\ge 3)$. This is $1-[\Pr(X=0)+\Pr(X=1)+\Pr(X=2)]$.

You were right to subtract from $1$, but should not have used $\Pr(X=3)$.

The expected number $E(X)$ is $np$, not $npq$.

The calculation of $\Pr(X=5)$ is correct.